# Neighbourhood of Scipy Labels

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I've got an array of objects labeled with `scipy.ndimage.measurements.label` called `Labels`. I've got other array `Data` containing stuff related to `Labels`. How can I make a third array `Neighbourhoods` which could serve to map **the nearest label to *x,y* is *L***

Given `Labels` and `Data`, how can I use python/numpy/scipy to get `Neighbourhoods`?

```
Labels = array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]] )

Data = array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
              [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]] )

Neighbourhoods = array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2],
                        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2],
                        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2],
                        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2],
                        [1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2],
                        [1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2],
                        [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]] )
```

Note: I'm not sure what should happen with ties, so used zeros in the above `Neighbourhoods`

Comment: Sounds like you want a [Voronoi diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram), although I'm not sure offhand if there is a function to compute it in Numpy/Scipy. I did a quick Google search and didn't find anything in Numpy/Scipy proper, but there are some blog posts and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by David Zaslavsky, this is the job for a voroni diagram. Here is a numpy implementation: http://blancosilva.wordpress.com/2010/12/15/image-processing-with-numpy-scipy-and-matplotlibs-in-sage/

The relevant function is `scipy.ndimage.distance_transform_edt`. It has a `return_indices` option that can be exploited to do what you need (as well as calculate the raw distances (`data` in your example)).

As an example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import distance_transform_edt

labels = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]] )
i, j = distance_transform_edt(labels == 0, return_distances=False, 
                              return_indices=True) 
neighborhoods = labels[i,j]
print neighborhoods
```

This yields:

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

Comment: I added the relevant portion from the article. Hope that's okay!